# Why don`t we need to add built-in Angular Services into provider but it still works?

Tags: angular, angular-services

I am following a tutorial and it uses "Title" built-in service as an example.

Importing service to component Ts file

```
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

Then injecting to constructor and setting title.

```
constructor(private title: Title){ this.title.setTitle('My Title'); }
```

If I run application, it works fine and I don`t get any "no provider for Title" error as it is not provided into any where at all. But this is violating Angular Service rules.

Can you please explain if built-in services are exception when it comes to adding to provider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the documentation describes the `Title` service is provided in the `root` of the application:
https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/Title#provided-in

This means that the `Title` service is defined with `providedIn` configuration. `providedIn` at the `Injectable` gives an alternative approach for providing dependencies through DI, if this is used, there is no need to provide the service through the `providers` array in the module config.
See more details about `providedIn` here: https://angular.io/guide/providers#providing-a-service

Comment: I missed providedIn part in documentation. It is provided in 'root' automatically as you described. Thank you.